# Restoring Ubuntu 16.04 LTS backup

Tags: backup, encryption, deja-dup

I had Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed for a year of so but due to some little issues I decided to attempt the upgrade to 17.04. That didn't go very well as it got stuck and at restart I believe the OS was corrupted. My hard disk was encrypted but even with the correct key, it's unable to be mounted. The error message is

> The unlocked device does not have a recognisable file system on it.

Note that when I use 'recovery mode' and get to the terminal as root, I am able to view the files and read them, so the files are fine, just the OS is messed up.

On the corrupted disk I still can access the volume with efi, grub and some other configuration files.

I've always been backing up in a separate hard drive and I have now 279GB of duplicity files that I should hopefully be able to restore.

However when I try to restore in a different machine I get

> Blockquote
>   Invalid data - SHA1 hash mismatch for file:
>    duplicity-inc.20171130T013124Z.to.20171207T013134Z.vol1.difftar.gz
>    Calculated hash: 430ed22ced70011xxxxx31b5b87b58da197
>    Manifest hash: 05252a1a9a5ffe8aexxxxx549c04e82a857e001f
>   Blockquote

This makes me think that the Deja-Dup that I have on the second machine is using a different key and for that reason it can't decrypt the backups.

Can you please help me finding a way to restore my old backups or move the files from terminal into another disk or fix the corrupted disk?

Comment: If I use try to access the disk after using recovery mode and logging in via terminal window I still see all my files there, any idea on how could I retrieve the files easily? When the Ubuntu 17 starts there is nothing in the desktop (no files, no apps, just the pointer). Tried to fix dpkg but also no luck there.